# How to pass a URL to Wget

Tags: grep, pipe, wget

If I have a document with many links and I want to download especially one picture with the name www.website.de/picture/example_2015-06-15.jpeg, how can I write a command that downloads me automatically exactly this one I extracted out of my document?

My idea would be this, but I'll get a failure message like "wget: URL is missing":

```
grep -E 'www.website.de/picture/example_2015-06-15.jpeg' document | wget
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using back ticks would be the easiest way of doing it:

```
wget `grep -E 'www.website.de/picture/example_2015-06-15.jpeg' document`
```

Answer (score 12):

Use xargs:

```
grep etc... | xargs wget
```

It takes its stdin (grep's output), and passes that text as command line arguments to whatever application you tell it to.

For example,

```
echo hello | xargs echo 'from xargs '
```

produces:

```
from xargs  hello
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do too:

```
wget "$(grep -E 'www.website.de/picture/example_2015-06-15.jpeg' document)"
```